# UML class diagram not importing classes while forward engineering

Tags: java, import, class-diagram

I have designed a class diagram for an web application using star UML in which i have passed HttpServletRequest as a parameter into a method. When i create java file using that it didnt import HttpServletRequest. How i have to modify my class diagram to achieve this.

My UML:

[image]

Generated Class:

```
package Controller;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * 
 */
public class LoginController {

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public LoginController() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private ILoginService loginService;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private Logger logger;

    /**
     * @param loginVO 
     * @param map 
     * @param req 
     * @return
     */
    public String loginPost(loginVO loginVO, ModelMap map, HttpServeltRequest req req) {
        // TODO implement here
        return "";
    }

}
```

Help me to solve this issue...

Thanks in Advance...

**Edit 1:**

Am using Star UML